# How to sort (x,y) points on a plane

Tags: graphing-functions, sorting

I have a set of points on a plane $(x,y)$ which form a bounded region.  I need to sort the points in order as they appear while moving around the boundary of the region, starting at some user specified point.  My current algorithm looks for the closest point, and adds that, etc.  The trouble is that this fails when there is a sharp or pinch section, and the closest data point might not be the logical next one in the boundary line, so it skips over those points.

Are there any other algorithms I could use to get around this problem?
[image: region with a pinch]

Here is a simpler version which exhibits the problem and where it is more obvious than the above what it should look like if you remove the lines:
[image: more obvious example]

Comment: How is your boundary (line) defined? You need to follow it along, not just look for the nearest point...

Comment: The boundary line is the set of discrete data points.

Comment: If I showed you a set of points like yours without the curve already drawn through them, how would you know that I meant them to be connected the way you showed in the question and not in some other clever way? I don’t think you could. This isn’t a fault of your algorithm, it’s just a badly defined problem.

Comment: ok the example I showed above is maybe too generic, my problem is a little smoother and more obvious what it looks like if you remove the lines, I will add the image to the post as I am not sure how to do it here.